# Getting a crash on startup with a fresh install with Risk of Rain

Tags: windows-10, risk-of-rain

I am attempting to launch risk of rain on a fresh copy of windows 10. I have installed my latest graphic drivers, C++ distributables and DirectX, however, the game goes black on startup, crashes, and pops out this ugly message:

[image: Risk of Rain Error]

Are there any known fixes for these?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What a waste of a bounty.

I have installed Microsoft XNA framework on my PC and Risk of Rain works now.

A bit of background, I dug into the annals of my memory and read somewhere that Risk of Rain was developed in GameMaker. The developers jumped through many hoops to get this game cross-platform (so it works on mac and linux too). That said, Game Maker requires the XNA framework and should install it if you install gamemaker.

However, that's jumping through hoops yourself. Microsoft offers the redistributable package from their website, and you should be able to find it [Here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=20914). File Size - 6.7Mb

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you should clear your registry first of the entries of the game

Comment: That is unlikely to work. I just posted an answer which fixed my issue. I installed the XNA framework redistributable from MS